# Mark on document where input starts and what is the filename

Tags: input, include, watermark

I have a master document, and use many `input{...}` commands to compile the total document from many parts.

I would like to mark on the working document, the start of each new `input`, and, what the filename was at that point.

I could renew the `\input{..}` command, but I do not want the mark to disrupt what would otherwise be the standard ouput, ie, the mark should be an underlay / watermark.

Is there a package that does this, I am thinking something similar to what the  `showkeys` package does.

I had the following in mind, to create a label whenever input is used, relying on `showkeys` do do the underlying marking on the document, but it isn't working:

```
\let\oldinput\input
\newcounter{inputcounter}\setcounter{inputcounter}{0}
\renewcommand{\input}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{inputcounter}%
    \label{inp:\theinputcounter:#1}%
    \oldinput{#1}%
}
```

Comment: Are you using `\input` inside floats as well?

Comment: possibly, assume yes.

Comment: in fact, definitely yes.

Comment: Do the `\input`ed files contain verbatim content?

Comment: More than likely tikz code for images, and, source code for listings, but also, chapters, sections, subsections, so, basically everything.

Comment: @Werner, see updated question for what I am trying to do.

Comment: It works fine for me when you use your redefinition of `\input`. What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: throws an error from `pgfrcs.sty`, file 'p.tex' not found, looking at pgfrcs.sty, it has: `\input pgfutil-common.tex` and `\input pgfutil-latex.def` so I dont know what is going on.

Comment: LaTeX's `\input` is set up to allow both plain TeX and LaTeX-like syntaxes. You probably want to redefine `\@iinput`, which is used internally with the LaTeX-like version.

Comment: @Joseph Genius. That worked. Cheers. If you want to post an answer, ill tick it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX definition of `\input` is designed to allow both the standard LaTeX braced-argument syntax

```
\input{filename}
```

and the original primitive syntax

```
\input filename % Space-terminated
```

However, you've redefined it such that it will only work with the LaTeX syntax. If you take a peek at the definition of `\input`, you'll find that the LaTeX syntax branch is handled by `\@iinput`. So that's the place to make a change

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{inputcounter}
\let\old@iinput\@iinput
\renewcommand{\@iinput}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{inputcounter}%
    \label{inp:\theinputcounter:#1}%
    \old@iinput{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

This assumes that you don't want to track use of the primitive syntax use, which is probably being used only by cross-format packages like `pgf`.

Comment: What would be the best way to place a horizontal rule (dashed) the width of the page, at the label location, without shifting any of the subsequent content down in any way, ie, non-disruptive?