# \renewcommand of \input for embedding input files without embed ALL source files

Tags: input

I would like to redefine the `\input` command so that it also embed the input file to the generated `pdf`. So far I used the code from thi s question ([Mark on document where input starts and what is the filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115488/mark-on-document-where-input-starts-and-what-is-the-filename)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\latex@iinput\@iinput
\renewcommand{\@iinput}[1]{%
    \latex@iinput{#1}%
    \embedfile[desc=input file]{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \input{input-prova.tex}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works but it has a problem: when I use other packages as `pgfplots` my redefinition of `\input` affect also `\input`'s commands present in the package's source codes and in my final `pdf` I have all these files embedded..

The second problem is that when I try to add an argument to this command in this way:

```
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\latex@iinput\@iinput
\renewcommand{\@iinput}[2][input file]{%
    \latex@iinput{#2}%
    \embedfile[desc=#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \input[file description]{input-prova.tex}
\end{docmuent}
```

I get an error...

I know that both problems can be resolved by defining my own command lie this:

```
\newcommand{\myinput}[2][input file]{%
    \input{#2}%
    \embedfile[desc=#1]{#2}%
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a way of doing it without changing the name of the `\input` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to modify the internal command, but the user level one.

```
\makeatletter
\let\latex@input\input
\newcommand\red@input[2][input file]{%
  \embedfile[desc={#1}]{#2}\latex@input{#2}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\input\red@input}
\makeatother
```

This will ensure only `\input` commands after `\begin{document}` will cause embedding of the source. However, some package might use `\input` at runtime, and also these file will be embedded. Commands that directly use the internal command `\@iinput` will not cause embedding.

Also changing the syntax of a documented command is not the best approach, so I'd go with a new command:

```
\newcommand{\sourceinput}[2][input file]{%
  \embedfile[desc={#1}]{#2}\input{#2}%
}
```

and use `\sourceinput` for the files I really want to be embedded.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that packages input files only when loaded but if they can do it also at the runtime then I will use your second option

Comment: `\embedfile[desc={#1}]{#2}` for the case that the description contains square brackets.